# How to show that these functions are equivalent for $x \to 0$?

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, sequences-and-series, limits, products

Let $\{p_n(x)\}_{n=1}^{+\infty}$ be a set of functions such that for $\forall x \in \mathbb{R} \forall n \in \mathbb{N}: 0 < p_n(x) < 1$ and $\sum\limits_{n=1}^{+\infty} p_n(x) = x$. I wonder if it is always true that $1 - \prod\limits_{n=1}^{+\infty} (1-p_n(x)) \sim x$ as $x$ goes to $0$?

So can someone prove the equivalence in general or provide a counterexample? **If a counterexample exists**, I'm interested in finding $\{p_n(x)\}_{n=1}^{+\infty}$ that minimizes the following limit:

$$\lim\limits_{x \to 0}\dfrac{1- \prod\limits_{n=1}^{+\infty} (1-p_n(x))}{x}$$

If the limit above can be equal to $0$ for some $\{p_n(x)\}_{n=1}^{+\infty}$, I would be interested to see any example of such sequence.

Any ideas, suggestions, hints and **references** related to the problem would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since
$$
\prod_{n=1}^{\infty} (1-p_n(x)) \leq \exp(-\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} p_n(x)),
$$
you get
$$
\frac{1 - \prod_{n=1}^{\infty} (1-p_n(x))}{x} \geq \frac{1 - e^{-x}}{x}, \qquad x\in (0,1),
$$
hence
$$
\liminf_{x\to 0} \frac{1 - \prod_{n=1}^{\infty} (1-p_n(x))}{x} \geq 1.
$$
On the other hand, since $0< p_n(x) < x$ and, for every $x\in (0,1)$, $\log(1-t) \geq -t/(1-x)$ for every $t\in [0, x]$, we get
$$
\frac{1 - \prod_{n=1}^{\infty} (1-p_n(x))}{x}
\leq
\frac{1-\exp(-\frac{x}{1-x})}{x}
$$
hence
$$
\limsup_{x\to 0} \frac{1 - \prod_{n=1}^{\infty} (1-p_n(x))}{x} \leq 1.
$$

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I didn't get, why $\liminf_{x\to 0} \frac{1 - \prod_{n=1}^{\infty} (1-p_n(x))}{x} \geq 1$? How it follows from inequality above? Because, actually, $\frac{1 - \prod_{n=1}^{\infty} (1-p_n(x))}{x}  \ge \frac{1-e^{-x}}{x} \le 1$, so 1 doesn't seem to be a lower bound.
As regards to the upper bound, it is quite clear, and there is another simple argument: $1 - \prod_{n=1}^{\infty} (1-p_n(x)) < x$, so the limit is not greater than 1.

Comment: $\liminf_{x\to 0} \cdots \geq \lim_{x\to 0} \frac{1-e^{-x}}{x} = 1$. I'm not sure whether the inequality $1-\prod(1-p_n(x)) < x$ is correct.

Comment: Since $p_n(x) \in (0,1)$ and $\sum_n p_n(x) < \infty$ then $\sum_n \log(1-p(x))= (1+o(1)) \sum_n p_n(x)=x+o(x)$ and $1-\prod_n (1-p_n(x)) = 1-e^{-x+o(x))} = x+o(x)$

Comment: @Ragel Now it's clear, thanks! The inequality is correct, because $\prod\limits_{k=1}^{n} (1-a_k) \ge 1-\sum\limits_{k=1}^{n} a_k$ by Bernoulli's inequality